# AngularJS Animate error: no method 'classNameFilter'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS app.js file I have added ngAnimate as per documented. However, I'm getting a strange error:

**Object [object Object] has no method 'classNameFilter' - angular-animate.js:297**

Why?

**This is my code:**

```
var app = angular.module('RegisterApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router',
])


app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {

            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/static/html/partials/_register.html"

        })
      .state('register', {

            url: "/register",
            templateUrl: "/accounts/registration-form/"

        })

});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.0/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/restangular/latest/restangular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore.js"></scri
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/javascript/utils/loading-bar.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/javascript/register.js"></script>
```

Comment: may be a version clash: angular: 1.2.1 angular-animate: 1.2.7?

Comment: @mseemann you were correct thanks. would you recommend updating to angular 1.2.7?

Comment: yes i would use 1.2.7:)

Comment: If you @mseemann would like to add an answer to reflect your comment I will accept. thank you for you help.

Comment: Crap I get this error and I use ver 1.2.7 for all modules.

Comment: Oh I did have 2 versions of angular in my page by mistake. Turn out glob expressions are not always your friend. This answer IS really helpful. THX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As investigated together with Spike: one should make sure that the version of angular and angular-animate is equal - in this case both should be 1.2.7.